# How to visualization RGB histogram

Tags: histogram

How can i to visualization RGB histogram?

I have array of:

```
int[] r;
int[] g;
int[] b;
```

I want draw RGB histogram, but I do not know how it works.
I choose the highest value: `MAX(r,g,b);` on the index and plott to graph?